# getIsResizeEnabled() is not working on Magento Backend

Tags: magento2, php, phtml

On Magento 2.3.2 version isResizeEnabled() is not working properly. It is throwing fetal error in the admin panel while I am going to the slider editing page.

```
<div id="id_nupIqHg2SWgdt9sX90VPMMTLKEwINXoQ_Uploader" class="uploader" data-mage-init="{
        'Magento_Backend/js/media-uploader' : {
            'maxFileSize';: 33554432,
            'maxWidth': 1920,
            'maxHeight': 1200,
            'isResizeEnabled': <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getIsResizeEnabled() on null in /mnt/home/sparkitbd/public_html/demo/outfitbd/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/media/uploader.phtml:18
Stack trace:
#0 /mnt/home/sparkitbd/public_html/demo/outfitbd/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include()
#1 /mnt/home/sparkitbd/public_html/demo/outfitbd/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(271): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Backend\Block\Media\Uploader), " mnt="" home="" spark...',="" array)="" #2="" sparkitbd="" public_html="" demo="" outfitbd="" vendor="" magento="" framework="" view="" element="" template.php(301):="" magento\framework\view\element\template-&gt;fetchview('="" spark...')="" #3="" module-backend="" block="" template.php(129):="" magento\framework\view\element\template-&gt;_tohtml()="" #4="" abstractblock.php(1094):="" magento\backend\bl="" in="" <b="">/mnt/home/sparkitbd/public_html/demo/outfitbd/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/media/uploader.phtml on line <b>18</b><br>
</div>
```

The code for uploader.phtml is below:

```
<div id="<?= $block->getHtmlId() ?>" class="uploader"
    data-mage-init='{
        "Magento_Backend/js/media-uploader" : {
            "maxFileSize": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getFileSizeService()->getMaxFileSize() ?>,
            "maxWidth": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getImageUploadMaxWidth() ?>,
            "maxHeight": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getImageUploadMaxHeight() ?>,
            "isResizeEnabled": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getImageUploadConfigData()->getIsResizeEnabled() ?>
        }
    }'
>
```

Comment: were you able to find solution. I am facing same error

Answer (score 0):

You added dynamically this way in ***content.php*** file inside ***_prepareLayout()*** fucntion

```
$this->addChild(
      'uploader',
      \Magento\Backend\Block\Media\Uploader::class,
      ['image_upload_config_data' => $this->imageUploadConfigDataProvider]
);
```

Ex:

```
/* add chiled as uploade block */
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->addChild(
    'uploader',
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Media\Uploader::class,
    ['image_upload_config_data' => $this->imageUploadConfigDataProvider]);

    $this->getUploader()->getConfig()->setUrl(
    $this->_urlBuilder->addSessionParam()->getUrl('categorygallery/multiple/upload')/* here set you upload Controller */
)->setFileField(
    'image'
)->setFilters(
    [
        'images' => [
            'label' => __('Images (.gif, .jpg, .png)'),
            'files' => ['*.gif', '*.jpg', '*.jpeg', '*.png'],
        ],
    ]
);

}
```

Comment: Please refer below link for more details : https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/magento/magento2/23434/506291522

Comment: Can't see how this response provides any kind of answer to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Appears Magento have changed something to do with how the media uploader is used. If you're responsible for the module that is now failing, best see if you can figure out how they expect it to be done now!

If you're just trying to fix someone else's code so that your customer's site works again after a Magento2 "upgrade", and there's no fix from the developer, this article properly explains how to go about solving this: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23825

Don't you just love how the new Magento2 team seem to have zero regard for maintaining backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a third party module not updated anymore.

For me, the image uploader was loaded by XML in `app/code/[VENDOR_NAME]/[MODULE_NAME]/view/adminhtml/layout/[name]_wysiwyg_images_index.xml`

I had this line:

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Wysiwyg\Images\Content\Uploader" name="wysiwyg_images.uploader" template="Magento_Cms::browser/content/uploader.phtml"/>
```

I've changed that to:

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Wysiwyg\Images\Content\Uploader" name="wysiwyg_images.uploader" template="Magento_Cms::browser/content/uploader.phtml">
        <arguments>
          <argument name="image_upload_config_data" xsi:type="object">Magento\Backend\Block\DataProviders\ImageUploadConfig</argument>
        </arguments>
</block>
```

According to magento core file:

```
vendor/magento/module-cms/view/adminhtml/layout/cms_wysiwyg_images_index.xml
```

**Magento Version 2.4.0**

Good Luck!